# invalid syntax for a big list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I found a big table of data online. I would like to use it in python. I was going to make a graph out of two of the columns of data.

I copy and pasted the table trying to make a string out of it but the table is just raw numbers no commas or anything and python isn't happy with that.

Is there any way I can do this in python?

(I added the first couple of commas experimenting)

```
import math
```

a=(
1983,  937.700,  645  1580  71.6  65.9  65.9  65.8  65.8
1984  3426.020  645  6742  76.8  67.8  67.4  60.5  61.6
1985  3189.450  645  6347  72.4  71.1  69.1  56.4  59.3
1986  3792.140  645  7488  85.5  85.8  74.2  67.1  61.7
1987  4658.460  640  7654  87.4  85.5  76.8  83.1  66.7
1988  5283.590  640  8372  95.3  95.3  80.4  94.0  71.9
1989  4870.250  640  7722  88.2  89.5  81.8  86.9  74.3
1990  4080.560  640  7748  88.4  72.9  80.6  72.8  74.1
1991  3925.510  640  6317  72.1  69.9  79.3  70.0  73.6
1992  4701.500  640  7431  84.6  84.8  79.9  83.6  74.7
1993  4827.100  685  7731  88.2  92.4  81.2  80.4  75.2
1994  5405.460  635  8634  98.6  98.6  82.7  97.2  77.2
1995  4518.970  635  7229  82.5  82.5  82.7  81.2  77.5
1996  5241.980  635  8289  94.4  94.4  83.6  94.0  78.7
1997  4217.520  635  6901  78.8  78.8  83.2  75.8  78.5
1998  3825.060  635  6258  71.4  71.4  82.5  68.8  77.9
1999  3793.280  635  6132  70.0  69.9  81.7  68.2  77.3
2000  4886.200  635  7879  89.7  89.7  82.2  87.6  77.9
2001  4711.190  635  7766  88.6  88.3  82.5  84.7  78.3
2002  4532.290  635  7366  84.1  83.4  82.5  81.5  78.4
2003  3567.070  635  5833  66.6  65.2  81.7  64.1  77.7
2004  4875.390  635  7905  90.0  89.2  82.0  87.4  78.2
2005  4486.190  635  7329  83.7  83.5  82.1  80.6  78.3
2006  4595.250  635  7541  86.1  86.1  82.3  82.6  78.5
2007  4328.590  635  7126  81.4  77.8  82.1  77.8  78.4
2008  3648.410  635  6207  70.7  65.4  81.4  65.4  77.9
2009  3611.440  635  6039  68.9  64.9  80.8  64.9  77.4
2010  3490.450  635  5641  64.4  62.8  80.2  62.8  76.9
2011  3490.600  635  5861  66.9  62.8  79.5  62.8  76.4
2012  3911.560  )

File "", line 3
    1983,  937.70,  645  1580  71.6  65.9  65.9  65.8  65.8
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Python tuples require commas, you'll need to add those.

Comment: Hint: `'foo bar'.split()` will give you `['foo','bar']`

Comment: what you plan to do with this data? according to that store the data. string is just enclosed between quotes,tuples separated by commas

Comment: do that for every single number?

Comment: no just copy all and paste it in a string.

Comment: what do you mean i cant assign it to anything

Comment: it just gives me the same thing. invalid syntax below second number

Answer (score 0):

Create file with name data and csv extension like this `data.csv`. Paste the original values to files (not the commas you added). Now you can read this file:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```